# Changed my style.css file - Nothing happened

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I'm trying to create a wordpress theme and I'm coding on my local server using xampp.

After about 10 hours of pulling my hair out trying to fix errors I finally figure out how to get my theme uploaded, and changes that I make to the style.css file aren't being applied.

It uploads perfectly fine and I even tried changing the php files and that seemed to work fine.

Any suggestions?

PS. This is my css code

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font: 13px Tahoma;
}

body,div,hgroup {
 display: block;
}
body { 
 text-align: center; 
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 background-color: blue;
}

#wrapper{
 display: -webkit-box;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 border: 1px a2a2a2 solid;
 width: 90%;
 text-align: left;
}

#header { 
 font: 65px Tahoma;
 border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; 
}

#content { 
 width: 75%; 
 border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; 
 float: left; 
}

#sidebar { 
 width: 23%; 
 border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; 
 float: right; 
}

/*#delimiter { 
 clear: both; 
}*/

#footer { 
 border: 2px #a2a2a2 solid; 
}

/*.title { 
 font-size: 11pt; 
 font-family: verdana; 
 font-weight: bold; 
}*/
```

Comment: Try clearing your cache and browsing history - css is often cached leading to the page not updating even when you load a new file.

Comment: Should I re-upload after clearing or just reload the page?

Comment: Just close your browser and then reopen it and reload the page.

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't seem to work. Is it possible that it's not able to read my stylesheet for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I fixed it! It looks like wordpress needs to use the bloginfo('stylesheet_url') function to access the css file instead of just href="style.css".

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question in the comments, but for anyone who stumbles upon this;

You should always load WordPress Stylesheets and JS files "the Wordpress way" as noted in the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/)

Wordpress uses custom routing that requires you to load the Stylesheets from the theme directory. Rather than trying to use a relative URL like `/style.css` Or `style.css` always follow the guide linked above and use the `wp_enqueue_style()` function with either `get_stylesheet_uri();` or `get_template_directory_uri();` to locate the file.

**Edit:** Note that those are not the only two functions that can be used to locate the stylesheet. As noted above you can also use the `get_bloginfo()` or `bloginfo()` functions and pass one of the many parameters that accepts. Read about that in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_bloginfo/).